# Flex Error matchtype.h

Tags: c, compiler-construction, bison, flex-lexer

I am writing a simple flex program that takes some inputs and creates tokens for the parser.

**My code [ex4.l]**

```
%{
enum yytokentype{
NUMBER = 258,
ADD = 259,
SUB = 260,
MUL = 261,
DIV = 262,
ABS = 263,
EOL = 264
};
int yylval
%}

%%
"+"     {return ADD;}
"-"     {return SUB;}
"*"     {return MUL;}
"/"     {return DIV;}
"|"     {return ABS;}
[0-9]+  {yylval = atoi(yytext);return NUMBER;}
\n      {return EOL;}
[ \t]   {/*ignore whitespace */}
.       {printf("Mystery character %c\n",*yytext);}
%%
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 int tok;

 while(tok = yylex()){
  printf("%d",tok);
  if(tok == NUMBER)
        printf("=%d\n",yylval);
  else
        printf("\n");
 }
}
```

After this i ran the command `flex ex4.l` which generated a lex.yy.c file and when i tried to run this by using the `cc lex.yy.c -lfl` i got stuck with this error message. And i keep getting this error i am not sure what the problem is at all. i am stuck on this for very long. Please advice

**Error Message**

```
cc lex.yy.c -lfl
"/usr/include/sys/machtypes.h", line 33: syntax error before or at: typedef
cc: acomp failed for lex.yy.c
```

Comment: I presume that you are using Solaris and Sun Studio with the bundled `acomp` compiler. That's just a guess from the header file and error message; it would be good to add the platform, compiler, and flex version (`flex --version` will give you the flex version; `cc -V` might do the same for the C compiler.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line 11 of your flex input:

```
int yylval
```

is missing a semicolon.

Undoubtedly what is happening is that flex inserts an `#include` directive immediately following the code prologue, and the first file included (recursively) is `machtypes.h`. The error is flagged on the first non-preprocessor line of that file, presumably because the preprocessed C program is:

```
int yylval typedef struct   _label_t { long val[2]; } label_t;
```

which is a syntax error, as reported.

Comment: Oh man i can't thank you enough. you are a savior. can u please recommend good source for learning some basic of flex and bison? i am currently reading Flex & Bison by John Levine

Comment: @user2733436: Levine's book is great, although it doesn't cover all the new features. Beyond that, you can't use flex and bison without a good grasp of C; as with this question, almost all the really tricky flex/bison bugs are actually in the C code.

Comment: hey i have just asked a new question on bison. is it possible for u to answer it for me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26458080/bison-specification-and-precedence-order