# Bison specification and precedence order

Tags: c, bison

Given Bison Specification: %right TOK_ADD TOK_MUL

I was wondering what would be the precedence order of TOK_ADD and TOK_MUL.

Also in case i had Bison specification

```
%left TOKMUL TOKADD
%left TOKDIV
%left TOKSUB
```

I was wondering what would the precedence order of TOKMUL TOKADD TOKDIV
 and TOKSUB be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bison/yacc precedence order is lowest to highest -- the tokens on the first line listed have the lowest precedence while those on the last have the highest.  Multiple tokens on the same line (`TOKMUL` and `TOKADD` in your case) have the same precedence